# How to access inherited of inherited Canvas of TImage?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-7

My descendant `TMyImage = class(ExtCtrls.TImage)` needs to access the `TImage` inherited Canvas (of the `TGraphicControl` ancestor)

e.g.

```
procedure TMyImage.Paint;
var
  LCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  // need "inherited inherited Canvas"
  LCanvas := inherited (inherited Canvas); // of the TGraphicControl

  inherited;
end;
```

The above wont compile obviously.
Is this can be done without hacking `TGraphicControl` and using the private member `FCanvas`?

This works:

```
type
  THackGraphicControl = class(TControl)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
  end;

procedure TMyImage.Paint;
var
  LCanvas: TCanvas;
begin          
  // need "inherited inherited Canvas"
  LCanvas := THackGraphicControl(Self).FCanvas;
  with LCanvas do
  begin
    Brush.Bitmap := FAlphaPattern;
    FillRect(ClientRect);
    Brush.Bitmap := nil;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

But I was wondering if there was a solution that will not be version dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a technique similar to what you already have, but access the `Canvas` property instead of the `FCanvas` field. The `Canvas` property is protected, which means it's technically part of the control's interface, so you shouldn't worry about it changing in a future version. (It might still change, but it's not something you should worry about.)

```
type
  THackGraphicControl = class(TGraphicControl) end;

LCanvas := THackGraphicControl(Self).Canvas;
```